Why doesn't the MinimumLevel in Serilog work?
My project is based on .NET Core 7 and uses Serilog as the logging tool. I want the overall log output to be at the Information level by default, but I also want the logs under a specific namespace to be at the Debug level. My Serilog configuration is in Image 1, and the .NET Core program startup code is in Image 2. When I use Log.Debug("debug"); to write logs, the logs are not printed to the console, but when I use _logger.LogDebug("logDebug"); the logs are printed to the console. What could be the reason for this?




Where is your code that configures Microsoft.Extensions.Logging to use Serilog?

no massive screenshots please - put it in as code with some overview context

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78865381/serilog-sink-file-with-filter-not-worked-using-the-appsettings-json https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-debug/pull/18 TL;DR a sink pipeline has a min level that defaults to info. A sink can provide a more restrictive filter. So if you want debug info to console then a) top level minimum level must be debug b) console sink better not be filtering (bu=y default it wont though)

I haven't configured Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.

@RubenBartelink thank you for reply。Do you mean that I can only change the default level to Debug and then manually filter out logs from other namespaces? I can't set the default to Information and then manually specify Debug for a certain namespace? Why is it that ILogger can do this?

Not sure what you mean. When you create a logger, it has a min level. That min level defaults to Information. So Debug wont work. If you override the min level to Debug, then it will work. After that, the sinks and/or any filters you set up can do other things. But the first/most important thing that needs to happen is that the logger min level must be changed to see Debug messages?
